# Search bar in a dropdown list

Tags: css, search, drop-down-menu, toggle

I have a Wordpress site and, for the mobile version, I have a menu bar at the top with a dropdown list with the categories. I would like to add the search bar in as well.

I have a working dropdown list with the search bar included at the bottom, but when you go to click in the search bar the list goes back up. I was wondering what is the best possible way, or is there a possible way, to get it to stay down?

I have some JavaScript enabled where on the touch mobile device you click and it's a slide toggle. All relevant code is provided below:

HTML

```
<div id="nav-responsive">
  <div class="categories-responsive fssinclair_bold">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><h3 class="fssinclair_bold"></h3>
        <ul>
          <?php wp_list_categories('&title_li=') ?>
        </ul>
        <div class="search-responsive">
          <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
            <div id="search-inputs">
              <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="search-box" placeholder="SEARCH" />
              <input type="hidden" name="ref_url" value="<?php esc_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?>">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </li>     
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript for it to toggle on touch devices:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
   $('.categories-responsive').click(function(){
   $(this).find('ul#nav').find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution is to create a separate function to those elements or use stopPropagation so the child elements dont get fired on click events. Something like this:

```
onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();"
```

or this for your search field

```
$("#searchform").click(function(event){ event.stopPropagation(); });
```

Comment: I've had a good read of this and i am unsure if this is what may get it to work (or i may not understand as i am a novice at jQuery). Would there be a way that i could do click the top bar of the menu and dropdown, click it again and go back up rather than the 1 line of slideToggle? If that makes any sense! The searchbar stays put when i use slideDown just need another function to say click again to slide back up? Sorry if i'm making no sense i use bog standard jQuery!

Comment: Sorry, maybe i didn't understand what you asked correctly. You want a dropdown that you click a button it shows the options and when you click again it hides them?

Comment: Thats the main concept of it which is great but inside that list is a search box so even i click on that at the moment the list goes back up (its dead annoying!) It must be something to do in my JS so that you only click the top menu bar to toggle rather than other elements nested in it? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Ah ok! Let me see if i got it this time, so what you should do is create a separate function to those elements or use stopPropagation so the child elements dont get fired on click events.
Something like this: onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();"   or this for your search field $("#search").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();  
});

Comment: Wow thank you, i use this : $("#search").click(function(event){ event.stopPropagation(); }) and changed #search to #searchform and works a charm. I knew there was a way to do it and its a nice 1 line that is friendly and any one can understand, thanks for your time :)

Comment: If you edit your answer with the code you just gave me i can make it answered!